# Unable to download the tar file , extract and copy into specific directory in ubuntu

Tags: curl

I am trying to download the tar file, extract and copy into other directory in my docker tensor flow container by using the following command.

'curl http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz | tar xz -C tf_files'

It shows Error like

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Downloading something doesn't have anything to do with tensorflow or docker. This does have something to do with the use of cURL though.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your command pipeline (curl) is failing to fetch the archive. Most likely, you are behind a corporate proxy.

You have a couple of options here:

- Specify proxy settings with curl -p (better if you are planning to
  download many files through command line, but requires you to know
  the proxy settings).
- Download the files through a browser and then
  run the tar extraction command only (simpler for one-off downloads).